# Spring Boot REST Application - Encrypting and Decrypting certain JSON fields - How can I technically implement a one for all solution?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, encryption

In our **web-based application** (**Spring Boot REST Application**) we are in need of finding an optimal way to ***obfuscate/encrypt certain JSON fields***, such as phone number, credit card number, e-mail, tax id etc. This requirement is driven by *security reasons*, as we are talking about e-banking. We do **not** want the sensitive data to appear raw on-screen or when accessing F12's Network tab. We have come up with some high-level ideas, such as:

- Obfuscation/Encryption of the fields in each microservice.
- Obfuscation/Encryption of the fields when the flow of calls returns back to the **EDGE** Service (all requests arrive there). Requests containing obfuscated/encrypted fields will be obviously decrypted in the backend.

**Technically speaking, how could we actually achieve this, though?**

Some additional information around the matter are the following:

- The choice between using encryption or tokenization for the sensitive fields is an implementation detail for now. However, you are welcome to brainstorm about which one you think is the most suitable in the case described.
- If we proceed in obfuscating the sensitive fields, then the client will only be able to display these fields (for instance, show the masked card number). If the client(front-end part written in JS-Redux) needs to use the X value, then an obfuscated value would be useless. Therefore, we thought of including the obfuscated field along with a hashed field (hash from the original value) to the Client (among other fields irrelevant to the aforementioned issue). If the client actually needs to use the value, it will proceed in decrypting the relevant field and then use it.
- The fields to be obfuscated/encrypted could be added to the relevant application.yml, so that we can dynamically add or remove them.

Thank you a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably more an information security or software engineering question than Stack Overflow, however:

**TL;DR**:

Browsers cannot be trusted with your server side secrets.

Don't try and encrypt data for use in the frontend. If they need to decrypt it, then any user of the API can do the same thing, because you must have sent them the means to do so. You gain nothing and potentially open up new avenues for attackers.

It's already encrypted in transit (It's using TLS, right?), if they don't need to see the data don't send it. If "something" needs to be sent, mask it (ie credit card in a PCI compliant manner) and use an opaque identifier (ie a random UID) to allow the client to act on the sensitive data somehow without giving it away. Eg your API could return a credit card like this:

```json
  
  "credit_card": { "number" : "4509-XXXX-XXX1-2334", "id" : "a34tfa46a"},
```

And the user can send the same data back if they are choosing that one, or whatever.

The only reason to encrypt data that is sent to a browser is to make the server side stateless - the server encrypts data so that the client sends it back to the server, the browser would never actually get the cleartext.